# Categorization of figures of speech

Tags: metaphors, figures-of-speech

Is there a clear categorization of tropes?

Some talk of the four master tropes (Metaphor, Synecdoche, Metonymy, Irony),
Whereas some give [An extended, unsorted list of tropes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Figure_of_speech#Tropes)

Some talk about [the 13-18(?) types of metaphors](http://english.answers.com/figures-of-speech/the-15-types-of-metaphors),
Whereas some categorize types of tropes as matephors (Allegory, Parable...)

Is there a specific, clear categorization of Figures of speech?
So far from what I've gathered it may look like this:

- Figures of speech

  - Schemes
  - Tropes

    - Metaphor
    - Synecdoche
    - Metonymy
    - Irony

Each trope is further subdivided, in a way I'm not yet sure of.
Is it even mildly correct?

Comment: You could start with Lakoff and Johnson's _Metaphors We Live By,_ and then go [the list here](http://www.lang.osaka-u.ac.jp/~sugimoto/MasterMetaphorList/metaphors/).

Comment: Thanks, though many of the links are broken. The book seems great though.

Answer (score 1):

You are on the fringe of a vast subject here. This forms part of the immense study of rhetoric, which goes back at least as as far as Plato and Aristotle.

If you simply take a look at the Wiki entry on 'Figures of Speech' it will give you some idea of the sheer number of categories you might include. It also provides a bibliography, which you may find useful.

You should also, for starters, just look at the Wiki entry on 'Rhetoric'.

Hope this helps.  It could easily become a life's work!

Comment: So...I guess that's a no?;) I thought that at least some subdivision is available.

Comment: @EladR  As mentioned this is a vast and specialised subject on which I am not qualified to help you. You need to read the work of those with expertise in it.